# Unable to login to desktop 20.04

Tags: bash, login, desktop-environments, bashrc

I cannot login to Ubuntu 20.04 after installation of `zsh-shell`
I added an `exec zsh` on top of my `.bashrc` file to change my default terminal to make `zsh` my default shell. On reboot, I couldn't log in.On the login screen, I get redirected to the login screen every time.
I started the terminal from the login screen, tried to get the terminal and use the `startx` command to force through, this has become tedious could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

In the `.bashrc` move the `exec zsh` command to the near bottom of your `.bashrc` file, not at the topmost part of your bashrc file

Comment: Use `chsh -s /bin/zsh <user>` instead to switch login shell.